# linking clang lib allways undefined symbol

Tags: c++, ruby, compiler-construction, clang, swig

I have created an some classes I want to use with swig in order to generate ruby binding.
Everything is ok when I generate the code or compile the ruby module. But when a script load this module, there is an error:

```
undefined symbol: _ZTVN5clang5LexerE
```

I understand that this means that the problem is for the clang::Lexer. But I know I have 
set the lclangLex lib for this.

here is the command I use in order to link the objects files:

```
clang++ -shared -o parser.so parser.o Declarations.o -L. -L/usr/lib -L. -Wl,-O1,\
--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic \
-L/usr/lib  -lz -lpthread -lffi -lcurses -ldl -lm     -lruby -lclangLex -lclangAST \ 
-lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc -lLLVMCppBackendCodeGen -lLLVMCppBackendInfo \
-lLLVMTarget -lLLVMCore -lLLVMMC -lLLVMObject -lLLVMSupport
```

any idea ?

Comment: I think you link dynamically to clang and you should load libclang.so at runtime that provides this function.

Comment: Yes this module is linked dynamically to clang. But I don't really see what you want to tell me "you should load libclang.so at runtime"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the order of the libs given to the linker:

```
-lclangAST -lclangLex -lclangBasic
```

lclangAST must be given before lclangLex then I just had to add lclangBasic and everything works.